# R create interactive plot with slider which width could be changed like in Google Finance (sizeable time-window)

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts, ggvis, googlevis

R create interactive plot with slider which width could be changed, example below, I'm searching in `ggvis` `R` package, but other are also welcome :

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at `dygraphs` and `dyRangeSelector()`.

> The dygraphs package is an R interface to the dygraphs JavaScript
>   charting library. It provides rich facilities for charting time-series
>   data in R

For more information and examples, have a look at `dygraph`'s [github.io](https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/):

```
install.packages("dygraphs")
library(dygraphs)
lungDeaths <- cbind(mdeaths, fdeaths)
dygraph(lungDeaths) %>%
  dySeries("mdeaths", label = "Male") %>%
  dySeries("fdeaths", label = "Female") %>%
  dyOptions(stackedGraph = TRUE) %>%
  dyRangeSelector(height = 20)
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: that's what I'm looking for, but what is the time series underslider ? could I customize ?

Comment: @Qbik I'm not sure I understand what you mean ? Of course, you can customize: have a look at `?dySeries`.

Answer (score 4):

Highcharts/Highstock it's another great tool for this kind of plots and there is an awesome API wrapper in R: http://jkunst.com/highcharter/

[image]